# Function on ANY checkbox change on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery in general and I want to have a function activate when ANY checkbox on the page is checked or not. Then it should check what state the checkbox is "checked" or not.

I'm not sure how to do this as all the examples I'd seen require the name of the checkbox in order to work. I'd be fine if this was in Javascript aswell.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind dynamically your checkboxes to change event, and check if they are checked, then do a function of your choice.

```
$(document).on("change", ".chkelement", function(){
   if( $(this).is(":checked") )
   {
      //DO SOMETHING
   }
});
```

I recommend use a container other than "document", as close as possible to where checkboxes will be, but you get the idea right?

Comment: How do I dynamically bind my checkboxs to the change event? P

Comment: Replace ".chkelement" in my code with "input[type='checkbox']" to get ALL checkboxes no matter where they are in the document

Comment: Is there a way to get the checkbox name that was selected?

Comment: if( $(this).is(":checked") )
   {
      var name = $(this).attr("name"); 
   }

Comment: I got it - I think  I'm getting the hang of how JQuery operates now! Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Yup. Just remember that $(document).on("change", ".chkelement", function(){} will also apply to any new elements on the page you add later with class of "chkelement". Whereas $(".chkelement").on("change", function(){} will ONLY apply to what you CURRENTLY have on the page at the moment with class of "chkelement".

Answer (score 4):

`$('input[type="checkbox"]')` would select all checkboxes on your page.

The following would run a function when any of your checkboxes are changed, and when checked:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {//do something}
})
```

Comment: Not what I want to do though, I want a function that will fire if a checkbox is changed.

Comment: Sheesh, give me a minute to finish typing before downvoting.

Comment: How dare you guys downvote an answer written by someone with 26k reputation. :D